# How to remove single chat through xmpp in iOS?

Tags: ios, xmpp, ejabberd

I am working on chatting app in iOS using xmpp and ejabberd . I am not able to remove single message.

Is this correct method `- (void)removeResources:(NSSet *)value` to remove chat? And what parameter I need to remove chat?

Or do I need to remove entry from core data? On Quick Blox I found this method:

```
NSSet *mesagesIDs = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"54fdbb69535c12c2e407c672", @"54fdbb69535c12c2e407c673", nil];      

[QBRequest deleteMessagesWithIDs:mesagesIDs
```

How to use this in my project without quickblox?

Comment: are you want to delete local message from core data ?

Comment: are you getting messages in array?

Comment: are you displaying message from core data ?

Comment: if yes then you have `XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject` message object . right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject`. i think this object is used to display data in `UITableView` so you can direct removed that object from core data using below code. Here i am showing to delete loop of messages.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
for (XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject *message in messages)
    {
        [moc deleteObject:message];

}
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: actually there is not such fuctionality integrated in  XMPP chat sample . you need to do your self.

Comment: But you can take reference, how to achieved that using code that is available in `XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage.m -- > - (void)didCreateManagedObjectContext` .. this method just show that how to delete composing message . so you can take reference of this/

Comment: i think that this may be solution.thanks                                                       where should i call this method?

Comment: implement on place where you want to delete the message and have object of XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject.

Comment: i add this code in - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle method,i need to delete message by swipe.             i  add {for (XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject *message in messages)
        {
            [moc deleteObject:message];
            
            if (moc == nil)
            {
                
            }
            else
            {
                
            }}   . but moc is getting nil

Comment: actually you need somehow get the reference of moc.
like NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];

Comment: Finally i do this code .correct me  { NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:messages];
        
        
        NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
         NSError *error;
        NSArray *objects = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

        
        for (XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject *message in messages)
        {
            [moc deleteObject:message];
            
            if (moc == nil)
            {
                
            }
            else
            {
                
            }
}

Comment: just delete single message instead of for loop.
for (XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject *message in messages)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79105/discussion-between-sri-krutarth-and-none).

Comment: @SriKrutarth, thanks for your appreciation, it keep us motivating. :)

Comment: Sir i want to reload the TableView. i try alot but not effective.  This is the  'IMMainMessageC' Class in Which 'initWithStyle' this is the Function that work for reloading when new message. i dont know how to Reload the TableView in XMPP when any Message Delete from Tableview.Thanks for advance.

Comment: @SawanCool, i assume that you have messages in `NSMutableArray`. so once you perform delete operation to delete data from core data. you also need to delete that object from NSMutableArray as well. and perform deleted row reloading of tableview using following code. [self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPathOfYourDeletedCell, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];